# forkjoin using javascript object or sourcesObject implementation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, fork-join

I have a piece of code that looks like this

```
getInformations().subscribe(
    informations => {
        let subs = [];
        for (const information of informations) {
            subs.push(getOtherDetails(information.id));
        }
        forkJoin(subs).subscribe(response => {
           //How can I Associate Information Id With The Response
            howToAssociateIdWithResponse();
     }}
);
```

---

**Situation** - I want to tie the responses of my second call with the ids of my first call, but I am running into issues.

**Attempted** - I tried the following but that seems to be throwing error

```
let subs: {[x:number]: Observable<any>}[] = [];
subs.push({information.id: getOtherDetails(info.id)})
```

but when I subscribed I got an error stating `You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

---

**Update - 1** After following @BizzyBob suggestion, the code looks like the following but my other logic is running before the subscription completes it's job. Here is what I mean

```
async ngOnChanges(){
    await getData(); //How to make sure below method only executes when this is really done.
    await useInformationReceivedFromgetData(); 
}
async getData(){
  getInformations().subscribe(
    informations => {
      let subs = [];
      for (const information of informations) {
         subs.push(getOtherDetails(information.id).pipe(
            map(data => ({ id: information.id, data })) // <---
         ));
      }
      forkJoin(subs).subscribe(objects => {           
         objects.forEach(({id, data}) => { /* saved to an arrray */ });
      });
   }

);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what line throws this error but maybe some of `getOtherDetails()` don't return Observable.

Comment: I think you should post the update in a new question since the original problem has been resolved.

Comment: Hi @BizzyBob - I just created https://stackoverflow.com/q/76414751/2719527 post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make each "getOtherDetails observable" emit an object with the `id` and response `data`:

```js
getInformations().subscribe(
   informations => {
      let subs = [];
      for (const information of informations) {
         subs.push(getOtherDetails(information.id).pipe(
            map(data => ({ id: information.id, data })) // <---
         ));
      }
      forkJoin(subs).subscribe(objects => {           
         objects.forEach(({id, data}) => { /* use id and data here */ });
      });
   }
);
```

---

Note, you can simplify your code by using .map() instead of creating a `subs` array and pusing to it:

```js
getInformations().subscribe(
   informations => {
      const subs = informations.map(
         ({id}) => getOtherDetails(id).pipe(map(data => ({ id, data })))
      );
      forkJoin(subs).subscribe(responses => {           
         responses.forEach(({id, data}) => { /* use id and data here */ });
      });
   }
);
```

---

Also, putting subscribes inside of subscribes is bad news.  You'd be better off to use a [Higher Order Mapping Operator](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) that will handle an "inner subscription" for you.  In this case, we can use `switchMap` to handle subscribing / unsubscribing to your forkJoin observable:

```js
getInformations().pipe(
   map(informations => informations.map(
      ({id}) => getOtherDetails(id).pipe(map(response => ({ id, data })))
   ),
   switchMap(requests => forkJoin(requests))
).subscribe(
   responses => responses.forEach(({id, data}) => { ... })
);
```

Comment: Thank you, how to await the `forkjoin.subscribe` to completely finish before I start using the values.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Logic in your subscribe will not execute until forkJoin emits a value. So, whatever logic you put there, will have the values.

Comment: let me quickly edit my question, your original solution helped the cause but I am still not where I want to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can lean way harder on `rxjs` and its pipe operators.
Consider following code:

```js
const combinedResults = getInformations().pipe(
  mergeMap((informations) => {
    return forkJoin(
      informations.map((information) =>
        getOtherDetails(information.id).pipe(
          map((detail) => ({ detail, id: information.id })),
        ),
      ),
    )
  }),
)

combinedResults.subscribe((combinedDetails) => {
  for (const information of combinedDetails) {
    const { detail, id } = information

    console.log('Now you have access to the detail and the id')
  }
})
```

It might look a bit crazy on first glance, but it reflects what you want to do in an "rxjs way".

1. fetch the general "informations"
2. use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) to use the result and map to a new observable
3. use Forkjoin to combine the array of `detail` observables
4. Map each `detail` response with the original response using the `map` pipe
5. Subscribe only once to read the combined values

This way enables you to easily display the result in an angular template using the `async` pipe. So if your goal is to display the combined values, you don't have to subscribe in your component logic at all, which is a gain because you don't have to think about performance or memory leaks. Read [this](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#unwrapping-data-from-an-observable) for more info

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (combinedResults | async)">{{item | json}}</div>
```