# How to await forkjoin.subscribe to use the values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

This is a continuation from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76410668/2719527) but I am creating a new post as it is different the original question.

**Question** - How to await forkjoin to complete before I run other business logic.

**Code Below**

```
export interface indexLogic {
  [id: number]: Detail;
}
async ngOnChanges(){
    await getData(); 
    //How to make sure below method only executes 
    //when this.indexLogic is populated.
    await useInformationReceivedFromgetData(); 
}
async getData(){
  getInformations().subscribe(
    informations => {
      let subs = [];
      for (const information of informations) {
         subs.push(getOtherDetails(information.id).pipe(
            map(data => ({ id: information.id, data })) // <---
         ));
      }
        this.indexLogic = [];
          forkJoin(subs).subscribe(objects => {           
             objects.forEach(({id, data}) => { this.indexLogic.push({[id]:data}) });
          });
       }
    
    );
}
```

Comment: @BizzyBob - here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that the forkJoin operation is completed before running other business logic, you can make use of the toPromise method and await the result.

```
export interface indexLogic 
{
    [id: number]: Detail;
}

async ngOnChanges() 
{
    await this.getData();
    await this.useInformationReceivedFromgetData();
}

async getData() 
{
    const informations = await getInformations().toPromise();
    const subs = [];
    for (const information of informations) 
    {
        subs.push(getOtherDetails(information.id).pipe(
        map(data => ({ id: information.id, data }))
        ));
     }

     this.indexLogic = [];
     const objects = await forkJoin(subs).toPromise();
     objects.forEach(({ id, data }) => 
     {
          this.indexLogic.push({ [id]: data });
     });
}

async useInformationReceivedFromgetData()  
{
   // Business logic that depends on this.indexLogic being populated
}
```

the getData method is modified to use the toPromise method instead of subscribing to the observable directly. This allows you to await the result and ensure that the asynchronous operations are completed before moving forward.
the forkJoin operation is also converted to a promise using toPromise to make it awaitable. The result is then stored in the objects variable, and the business logic in the useInformationReceivedFromgetData method can be executed safely knowing that this.indexLogic has been populated.

Comment: Has no sense convert to Promise. Just write the code **inside** the "subscribe function"

Comment: @Eliseo - I am unable to use the technique you mentioned for some reason. Could you help with an example? Let me know if you would like me to update the problem with more code so you see why I couldn't.

Comment: @VivekShukla, it's only call the function inside subscribe function, see my answer

Comment: I downvoted this. The goal of the question is actually quite straightforward. As other comments point out, OP just wants to subscribe to the result and perform the logic then. Converting to a Promise to use async/await bloats up the code with no benefit and it kind of shows, that you do not understand how to use rxjs properly. No hate here, but what I want to say is that your answer does not seem appropriate to me.

Comment: @LaurenzHonauer And that's not for OP to decide?

Comment: @Locoz no.

Unnecessary complexity in code is objectively bad. That's not for anyone to decide, that's a universal truth.

Again, I meant no harm with the downvote. I didn't downvote you, but the code in your answer. If I offended you with my comment, I'm sorry. Peace

Comment: @Locoz - I am unable to upvote your answer, could you edit the answer by adding some  space or some blurb so I could upvote it, as I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

complementary my comment, it's unecessary convert to Promise

```
    forkJoin(subs).subscribe(objects => {           
         objects.forEach(({id, data}) => { this.indexLogic.push({[id]:data}) });
          ..here you write any thing o call a function
          this.doSomeThing()
      });
```

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo - This is exactly what I have tried but html page was rendered before the logic inside the subscription was called, so I thought maybe I will use an await call in my `ngOnInit/ngOnChanges` method to make sure result has been awaited.

Comment: you always can use an auxiliar variable, e.g. `yet:boolean=false` and after doSomething() do `this.yet=true`. Put all you need under a `*ngIf="yet"`

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me realize a flaw in my concepts. I found out that, there was a boolean variable being set outside of the subscribe of `forkJoin` , and moving the variable inside forkJoin's subscribe could have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `indexLogic` contains data from asynchronous actions and that you want to react as soon as it changes its value means that `indexLogic` should be considered asynchronous. That means it makes sense to save the information as an Observable which can be subscribed later on.

Check out the code below (referencing stuff I answered in your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410668/forkjoin-using-javascript-object-or-sourcesobject-implementation))

```
type Detail = {
  id: string
}
type IndexLogic = {
  [id: string]: Detail
}

export class InformationComponent {
  indexLogic$ = new Observable<IndexLogic[]>()

  ngOnInit(): void {
    getInformations()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((informations) => {
          return forkJoin(
            informations.map(({ id }) =>
              getOtherDetails(id).pipe(map((detail) => ({ [id]: detail }))),
            ),
          )
        }),
      )
      .subscribe((indexLogic) => {
        useInformationReceivedFromgetData(indexLogic)
      })
  }
}
```

Also note that I moved the code into `ngOnInit` which might be what you want instead of `ngOnChanges`as I suspect you want to fetch the Data when your Component *inititializes*.

Additionally, as you can see there is no `async` keyword in the code. async/await is a nice feature in javascript, but since you are working with Observables you might not want to use it here. RxJs already comes with an opinionated way to do stuff, mixing this with async/await might make your life harder than easier.

Comment: Thank you @Laurenz - I will have to read up a bit about various methods such as `mergeMap` in conjunction with `return forkJoin` to make sure I fully understand it.